# If you use Tensorflow Dataset do you have to upload your data?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have been looking at Tensorflow Dataset (TFDS) and seems really useful. The only issue I can see is that if you want to use it, you have to upload your dataset publicly to TFDS. Is that correct?
Is there anyway of using TFDS on a private server? Only for internal use?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create new local datasets, as described in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset#tldr). Here's an excerpt:

```
class MyDataset(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder):
  """DatasetBuilder for my_dataset dataset."""

  VERSION = tfds.core.Version('1.0.0')
  RELEASE_NOTES = {
      '1.0.0': 'Initial release.',
  }

  def _info(self) -> tfds.core.DatasetInfo:
    """Dataset metadata (homepage, citation,...)."""
    return tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
        builder=self,
        features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
            'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(256, 256, 3)),
            'label': tfds.features.ClassLabel(names=['no', 'yes']),
        }),
    )

  def _split_generators(self, dl_manager: tfds.download.DownloadManager):
    """Download the data and define splits."""
    extracted_path = dl_manager.download_and_extract('http://data.org/data.zip')
    # dl_manager returns pathlib-like objects with `path.read_text()`,
    # `path.iterdir()`,...
    return {
        'train': self._generate_examples(path=extracted_path / 'train_images'),
        'test': self._generate_examples(path=extracted_path / 'test_images'),
    }

  def _generate_examples(self, path) -> Iterator[Tuple[Key, Example]]:
    """Generator of examples for each split."""
    for img_path in path.glob('*.jpeg'):
      # Yields (key, example)
      yield img_path.name, {
          'image': img_path,
          'label': 'yes' if img_path.name.startswith('yes_') else 'no',
      }
```

Comment: `extracted_path = dl_manager.download_and_extract('http://data.org/data.zip')` Would this still be local since it requires the dataset to be retrieved?

Comment: @BLUC that's just so it's a reproducible example. you don't need to download anything. the output of `download_and_extract` is just a folder with images. later, in `_generate_examples`, you can iterate through any other folder

Comment: NameError: name 'Iterator' is not defined... should it be done manually or what library to import else to get this class ?? (with Tuple the same problem if inheritance is done from tf.data..Iterator)... Anyway, thank you for the example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your datasets in `TFDS` you have to put your data in your `GCS bucket` or on your `drive`, but if you want that your data can be downloaded using some registration or password then your data also be implemented in TFDS but it was not directly downloaded and extracted by tfds data pipelines, user have to follow `manually downloading instructions` as given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset#manual_download_and_extraction).

Also there is a public GCS bucket of tfds in which you can also upload your data but before it you have to contact with members of TFDS (as they have to check if it's good to upload your data in tfds gcs), by putting data on TFDS GCS helps a lot it avoid some issues of bad servers as well as user can directly load your data using `tfds.load` API.